# VB syntax error for concatenate and evaluate

Tags: excel, concatenation, vba

I am trying to write a VB script that concatenates data together into a url string and then I want it to copy down into all the rows for that column.  I've got the fill down code working okay but when I try to add the concatenate I keep getting a syntax error so I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong.  I have tried two versions and they both give me syntax errors on the final line of script (right side):

**Script Version 1:**

```
Sub SetSurveyLink()

' SetSurveyLink Macro

Dim lngLastRow As Long
lngLastRow = Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
Range("C3:C" & lngLastRow).Value = EVALUATE("https://domainname.com/survey/?PartName=" & 'Client List'!B1 & "&ClientID="&B2)
End Sub
```

**Script Version 2:**

```
Sub SetSurveyLink()

' SetSurveyLink Macro

Dim lngLastRow As Long

lngLastRow = Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
Range("C3:C" & lngLastRow).Value = CONCATENATE("https://domainname.com/survey/?PartName=",'Client List'!B1,"&ClientID=",B2)

End Sub
```

The 'concatenate' string gives me the correct value when used in a cell (i.e. not as part of a script) but I just can't get it to work in the script. See anything that I'm missing in my syntax?

THANK YOU!

Comment: Thanks for fixing my code Shai, still learning best practices for posting.

Comment: YowE3k that is perfect. Thank you so much.

Comment: I've posted as an "answer" so it doesn't get deleted by comment cleanup

Comment: Is the idea to combine `https://...?PartName=` with the value in cell B1 of sheet Client List and put the result into a cell, or to create a formula in the cell that performs that process? Because the answer is going to be different depending on which you're after.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Any double-quote marks within a string need to be escaped to be double double-quote marks so, if

```
"https://domainname.com/survey/?PartName=" & 'Client List'!B1 & "&ClientID="&B2
```

worked within Excel, it becomes

```
""https://domainname.com/survey/?PartName="" & 'Client List'!B1 & ""&ClientID=""&B2
```

and then you need to enclose that within double-quote marks to make it a string literal within VBA, i.e.

```
"""https://domainname.com/survey/?PartName="" & 'Client List'!B1 & ""&ClientID=""&B2"
```